# Laravel extract day from datetime

Tags: laravel, datetime, properties

I have a datetime property in the model

```
 public function getStoryDateDayAttribute()
{
    return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->attributes['story_date']));
}
```

I need to extract just the day like this:

```
@foreach($events as $event)
            <li>
                <time datetime={!! $event->story_date !!}>
                    <span class="day">4</span>
```

Which is the best way to achieve this? Do I have to make a method inside the Model or create a Helper string manipulation method?

Comment: You can use the `date()` function in the view, if you want. Entirely up to you which approach you take.

Comment: I don't know wyhich is the best way; neither my test is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend to read the [Carbon Library](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) documentation, since it's the default returned element for dates in Laravel. You can found more information [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

------- UPDATE ------

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['story_date'];
}
```

On your blade template

```
{{ $user->story_date->format('d') }}
```

Comment: {!! dd(Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $event->story_date)) !!} shows nothing... am i ujsing it wrongly?

Comment: Inside the Model class, you need something like that 

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'story_date'];

Comment: I have the story_date in the $fillable... do i have to create  static method for the class?

Comment: :) thanks but before thinking about lazyness it would be simpler to think that I couldn't find a a way to make it work... My attribute is already in Carbon format with a mutator --- public function setStoryDateAttribute($event_date)
    {
        $this->attributes['story_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $event_date);
    }     ------- The problem is that {!! $event->story_date->format('d') !!} does not shows anything

Comment: Maybe i should delete the accessor?

Comment: Try removing the accessor, and note that I'm using `{{` not `{!!`. Try both changes.

If you use the accessor then you can just display the {{ $event->story_date }}, because the accessor will be applied before.

Comment: {!! is used just to not escape data... $event->story_date shows the complete date, while $event->story_date->format('d-m-Y') shows nothing (because in blade $event->story_date is a string). I would like just to have the day.

Comment: Well I have tried it on my code without a problem. Either using {!! or {{. No mutators or accessors, just defining the field as date. And it works as expected. Btw, to just get the day on the format just type 'd'.

What do you get if you `dd($event->story_date)` ?